# Barras verticais valoradas com flot.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, flot

Olá.

Utilizo o [**flot.js**](https://github.com/flot/flot) para plotar um gráfico "Stacked Bars" [exemplo](http://www.flotcharts.org/flot/examples/stacking/index.html) mas eu queria inserir os valores das barras "dentro" da barra, e não simplesmente no tooltip.

Alguém sabe como fazer?

[image: Exemplo]

Answer (score 2):

Existe um plugin para fazer isso. Dei com ele à uns tempos quando estava a trabalhar numa [adaptação](https://github.com/SergioCrisostomo/Mootools-chart-flot) que eu fiz do Flot para MooTools.

O link do plugin é: https://github.com/leonardoeloy/flot-valuelabels

A parte nova necessária às options é , por exemplo:

```
series: {
    valueLabels: {
        show: true,
        showAsHtml: true,
        labelFormatter: function (v) {
            return v + '%';
        }
    },
```

Provavelmente vais ter de adaptar com CSS a posição exata do valor como eu fiz no exemplo usando `margin-top: 20px;`. Este plugin tem ainda a vantagem de ter uma função para mudar os valores, ie acrescentar o simbolo de percentagem ou correr uma função sobre os valores que mostra.

Nota que existe ainda outro plugin para empilhar as barras, o stack (que juntei ao meu exemplo também).O gráfico funciona também sem ele mas as barras ficam umas atrás das outras em vez de umas em cima das outras.

### [Exemplo](http://jsfiddle.net/x32Mr/)